# Sqldeveloper 2.* had handy Data Modeler - is there anything similar in Sqldeveloper3.*

Tags: oracle, database-schema, oracle-sqldeveloper

Sqldeveloper 2.* had a very good tool to view database schema. here is the screen-shot of how it can be launched:
[image: SqlDeveloper 2.* Data Modeler]

Was this tool removed from SqlDeveloper 3.* and is there something similar there?

P.S. I tried googling and reading manuals for some time, of course.

Comment: You can download the DataModeler as a separate product as well: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest versions of SQL Developer still have the data modeler.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html

here's a link that shows you, I use it almost daily in the latest version of sql developer (or at least 3.1.07 that I am using -->whoa they've updated to 3.2 I'll go get that later)

you can still goto Tools->Data Modeler but you can also OPEN and SAVE the datamodeler via the File->Data Modeler context menus (it seems to have been 'combined' with SQL DEVELOPER to the point where you save it independently).

If you go to VIEW->Data Modeler->Browser you can then create models etc and save them via the aforementioned menu item in SAVE.

Comment: The complete path to the functionality that was previously accessible on one click:
View/Data Modeler/Browser -> In the "Browser? view in any Design/Relational Models (create new or show existing with the context menu). In the new view you may drag the tables from connections.

Comment: it has been so long since I use 2.0's modeler (and even then I only used it sparingly compared to how much I have used 3's).  I think one of the stand-out features is the drag and drop tables from the connections to the relational model.  Even works for JDBC data sources -- including the referential integrity for SQL Server.  so not only for Oracle.